# Configuring java webapp to transfer data via http using curl command

Tags: java, tomcat, curl

I'm currently running a webapp on tomcat 8 and wish to show the receive the output of a certain post request on the terminal screen without rendering a webpage.  As an example, I'm looking to use a command similar to this:

```
curl -d "param1=xxx&param2=yyy" localhost:8080/webapp
```

and get a (short) response similar to this:

```
"some data here"
```

I do not want to get the HTML of a webpage that would be rendered if I hit the URL in a browser.  Is there any way that this can be done in Tomcat?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK response content is generated in Tomcat by the web application (servlet, JSP or whatever). You probably should create such a webapp which will output just a text without a tags and other html stuff, f.e. create a `index.jsp` file in tomcat webapps root directory (usually **tomcat_root\webapps\ROOT**) with this content (yes, just one short line):

`<%="some data here"%>`

You'll get raw data by this request, BUT this will anyway a HTTP response. If you plan to deal with this data on lower level (say TCP), you'll get from server extra data like headers values etc.

Additionally you probably have to care about setting correct headers in response, f.e.: `ContentType: text/plain`, if your client software cares about it. Or just skip it: you'll get raw text content anyway independently of content-type headers values.

Comment: Awesome answer.  I did make that webapp, and am presently using a servlet within that webapp to answer the 'get'.  However, the 'doGet()' and 'doPost()' methods in my servlet class are not called when I try to send a request to the server.  What can I do to remedy that issue?

Comment: @AWidget Could you please share your sample code to look at it and make corrections if needed? If you're using servlets instead of JSPs (JSPs actually are compiled to class files by servlet container), you have to put your compiled classes in `tomcat_root/webapps/ROOT/**WEB-INF/classes**` or if you have a jar - to `tomcat_root/webapps/ROOT/**WEB-INF/lib**`. Also you may have to correctly setup your web application descriptor (file `web.xml`), please see here: https://www.mkyong.com/servlet/a-simple-servlet-example-write-deploy-run/

Comment: OK - Here's the class with the web.xml.  I am using eclipse and I verified that that is indeed how the webapp is being deployed (with the clases going in WEB-INF/classes).  I also tried moving the application to 'ROOT' directory, but no avail:

When I start the server, the constructor (I can see the printed line) but the request handlers are ignored.

Comment: Servlet class:  [link](http://pastebin.com/BCnAS7AJ)
web.xml: [link](http://pastebin.com/qEYsvvYH)

Answer (score 0):

You must specify that the request is a POST request

```
$ curl -i -X POST  -d "param1=xxx&param2=yyy" localhost:8080/webapp
```